# Paypal Instant Payment Notification INVALID

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to implement Paypal IPN, i'm testing from sandbox ipn simulator, but always getting invalid, I can't realise what is happening.. I searched and everyone who had this problem used HTTP 1.0 but in this case that is not problem its 1.1 protocole. I hope someone who knows more about paypal api can help me.

Here is some outputs and code.

This is curl output that is made in the last step verification:
http://pastebin.com/1cMDEAUY

And full class if you need to see something more:
http://pastebin.com/vwKixapL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem, everything was setupped correctly, but their data for date in sandbox was invalid ( It was like this Sun May 22 2016 14:07:48 GMT+0200 (CEST) ), but then i found another paypal simulator https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator and date their was like 05:08:15 22 May 2016 PDT, and now it work.